# C++/CLI use of Action<...,...> and Func<...> unsupported?

Tags: .net, generics, .net-3.5, delegates, c++-cli

it does not look like there is support for the Action and Func delegates in the System namespace in C++/CLI. At least not for multiple generic arguments such as:

```
System::Action<int, int>^ action = nullptr;
System::Func<int, int>^ func = nullptr;
```

Both result in errors such as:

```
error C2977: 'System::Action' : too many generic arguments  
error C2955: 'System::Action' : use of class generic requires generic argument list
```

Only single argument Action works:

```
System::Action<int>^ action = nullptr;
```

Anyone, knows why or what is missing to make this work. I am using Visual Studio 2008 and the project has target framework 3.5.

Comment: Do you have a reference to System.Core?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The location of the `Action` and `Func` types is different depending on the framework version you are using.

In the 3.5 framework all definitions of `Func` (generic or not generic) reside in System.Core.dll.  This is also true for versions of `Action` with 2 or more generic parameters.  `Action` and `Action<T1,T2>` are in mscorlib though.

In the 4.0 framework all of the definitions of `Func` and `Action` moved to mscorlib.  There are type forwarders inserted into System.Core which point back to mscorlib now.

Silverlight 4.0 is closer to the 3.5 framework solution.

Make sure you have a reference to the appropriate DLL for your solution.

Comment: Indeed, this was the case. Adding System.Core.dll solved the issues. Thanks.

Comment: You, mention type forwarders in System.Core for 4.0. Do you know how this is possible to do yourself?

Answer (score 9):

The following are defined in mscorlib -

```
Action
Action<T>
```

But the following are defined in System.Core.

```
Action<T1, T2>
Func<T1, T2>
```

You're probably missing a reference to that assembly.