# C++/CLi IntelliSense: too many arguments for generic class "System::Action"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli

In a C++/CLI project targeting VS2012 (using VS2013) I'm getting the error `IntelliSense: too many arguments for generic class "System::Action"` on the following code:

```
public ref class MyClass
{
    event Action<String^>^ S1;
    event Action<String^, String^>^ S2; // error here
}
```

The code compiles fine, I just get the IntelliSense error =/

If I comment out the `event Action<String^>^ S1` line, then the error goes away on the second line. Basically, it looks like if I use both `Action<T>` and `Action<T1,T2>` in the same class (maybe file?) then IntelliSense gets confused.

This post ([C++/CLI use of Action<...,...> and Func<...> unsupported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193808/c-cli-use-of-action-and-func-unsupported)) indicates that `Action` was split between two files (mscorlib and System.Core) in the 3.5 framework, but I double checked and I'm referencing the 4.0 framework (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089), so I don't think that is it. And just to check, I added a reference to `System.Core` with no change in behavior.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It is a strange bug that defies a simple explanation, probably has something to do with the parser not handling [TypeForwardedTo] correctly.  Punt the problem and do this the right way, events ought to be `EventHandler<T>` to match the standard pattern.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it @HansPassant, I appreciate the second set of eyes. However, I'm not sure I would say that `EventHandler<T>` is the "right way," mostly because I don't need the sender, and if I did, I would want it to be strongly typed. From Microsoft: `Generic delegates are especially useful in defining events based on the typical design pattern because the sender argument can be strongly typed and no longer has to be cast to and from Object.` [Generic Delegates (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx2bwtw7.aspx)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I"m facing a similar problem in .net framework 4.7

Comment: Nope... =/ Though, I only worked on this for a few days 3 years ago and haven't checked again since